# Add all non-controlled files?

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm

I use phpstorm as my IDE, it has git version control integration built in so I have never needed to use the command line.

However I have run into a problem, a few times when I have been prompted "Do you wish to add this file/directory to git version control" I have clicked no, Hence I have some folders and files all over the place that are not under the control.

I am wondering if there is a command I can run that will add all these files to the version control for me?

Comment: Has it added those files/folders to a .gitignore to keep them from showing up as untracked? Or have they just not been added? (Look for a file called `.gitignore` at the top level of your repository.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get to a command line and change your working directory to your git repository.

```
$ cd /home/wesley/dev/mytwitterbook
```

Stage everything in the working directory and subdirectories

```
$ git add .
```

The next time you commit, *everything* that has not been `.gitignore`'d will be added to version control.

---

**NB:** `git add .` will also stage any files that are already version controlled. If you've made changes to any files since your last commit, you may want to avoid committing them. If so, stash your changes first:

```
$ git stash  # set aside any changes in VC'd files
$ git add .
$ git stash pop  # restore stashed changes
```

Comment: I think the OP doesn't want to stage everything, but only those files which currently aren't under version control. With `git add .`, you may add files which aren't supposed to be in the next commit.

Answer (score 7):

In PhpStorm you can open the **Changes** panel and in the **Local** tab you will see all the **Unversioned files** under the separate node. You can right click on this node or select individual files and then add them to version control at once. Then perform commit/push when ready.